# How can I delete the pages in an enormous PDF that do not contain a certain word at the top of the page? Hopefully in C#

Tags: c#, pdf

So I have this 2300+ pdf PDF that I need to deal with.  Step 1 has to be deleting the pages I don't need from it.  For example, pages 1 to 24 don’t contain any information that I need, then 25 to 28 I do need, 29 to 54 I don’t need, etc.  The number of each pages I do need and the number of pages I don’t need vary with each section.  But each page I do need to keep has the phrase "5 DAY M.A.R." at the top of the page, so any page that doesn't contain that needs to be deleted.

Ideally if there is a way to create a C# (or similar) application that does that then I could trigger it to run automatically since I need to setup a process that handles a PDF like this every hour.

Thanks for any advice.  I'm not opposed to paying for a product that does this but I couldn't find anything that quite did what I was hoping for.

Probably easier to leave edits up here:

Unfortunately I haven't done a lot, I was trying to use an older program that I wrote in C#, but it probably won't work. That older program was based on splitting a large PDF into smaller ones based on a series of "page 1 of 6" type footers on each page. I wasn't deleting any pages from that series, so I don't know where to start.  My C# is pretty rusty.  I tend to set something up and then forget about it.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I don't know C# but I assume it has a library that opens up PDFs, stream the lines in and check if they are what you want. Delete the ones that you don't want and then output the altered PDF.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't done a lot, I was trying to use an older program that I wrote in C#, but it probably won't work.  That older program was based on splitting a large PDF into smaller ones based on a series of "page 1 of 6" type footers on each page.  I wasn't deleting any pages from that series.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, if paid libraries are allowed you could go with Apitron PDF Kit for example, it supports formatted text extraction and text search. Page manipulation is also supported. As **yms** said, not all PDF files support text extraction, because there might be only font glyphs present with no info regarding to which chars they should map to. Hope it's not your case.

Answer (score 0):

If using a commercial library is an option, you could try with [Amyuni PDF Creator .Net](http://www.amyuni.com/en/developer/pdfcreator/features/)

Using this library you can iterate through all the elements of a page and retrieve the text (when available, since not all PDF files allow text extraction). You can then use the method [IacDocument.DeletePage](https://www.amyuni.com/WebHelp/Amyuni_PDF_Creator_for_WinRT/AmyuniPDFCreator_IacDocument/Methods/IacDocument.DeletePage_Method.htm) to remove pages from the document.

*Disclaimer: I work for Amyuni Technologies.*